# Problem in routing the network in GNS3

Tags: routing, gns3

Can someone please help me:
[image]

Cloud 5 is configured with a loopback adapter on my PC with ip 10.84.104.254.
R1 F0/1: 10.84.104.1

i am able to ping R1 F0/1 from outside, as well as I can ping and do all the functionalities from R1 F0/0 to internal network. But when I am trying to ping R2 F0/0 (192.168.12.2) from outside, its not reachable.

I guess the communication is not taking place between the fastethernet port f0/0 & f0/1 on router R1.

Please suggest:

```
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 10.84.104.254 to network 0.0.0.0

C    192.168.12.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
     192.168.14.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       192.168.14.5 [110/41] via 192.168.12.2, 00:12:56, FastEthernet0/0
O    192.168.45.0/24 [110/40] via 192.168.12.2, 00:12:56, FastEthernet0/0
O    192.168.24.0/24 [110/11121] via 192.168.12.2, 00:12:56, FastEthernet0/0
     10.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       10.84.104.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
O    192.168.23.0/24 [110/20] via 192.168.12.2, 00:12:57, FastEthernet0/0
O    192.168.34.0/24 [110/30] via 192.168.12.2, 00:12:57, FastEthernet0/0
S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 10.84.104.254
```

Router Configuration:

```
    hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip multicast-routing
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.12.1 255.255.255.0
 ip pim dense-mode
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.84.104.1 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-mode
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0
 default-information originate
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.84.104.254
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Second Router:

```
    hostname R2
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip multicast-routing
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 192.168.24.2 255.255.255.0
 ip pim dense-mode
 tunnel source FastEthernet0/1
 tunnel destination 192.168.34.4
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.12.2 255.255.255.0
 ip pim dense-mode
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.23.2 255.255.255.0
 ip pim dense-mode
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 passive-interface Tunnel0
 network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Comment: Please do not use an image for text. Edit your question to remove the image of the screenshot and paste the text directly into the question, using the Preformatted Text feature (`{}`). You also, need to include the router configurations.

Comment: You also, need to include the router configurations, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: I thought of trying with different IP network, so I have also tried with 192.168.10.0 in place of 10.84.104.0

Comment: You only included one router configuration. We need to see both router configurations.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

On R1, you have a routing mess. Mixing multiple routing protocols and static routes can lead to problems unless you really know what you are doing. AD (Administrative Distance) will prefer the static routes. Since you are only running OSPF on R2, then you should stick with that, except for a default route, which you should inject onto OSPF. Your OSPF network statement are really incorrect, but the last one (`network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0`) will include every interface, so it is the only one you need.

**R1 corrections:**

```
no router eigrp 1
!
router ospf 1
 no network 10.84.0.0 0.0.0.0 area 0
 no network 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.0 area 0
 default-information originate
!
no ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.12.2
no ip route 10.84.104.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.12.0
no ip route 10.84.104.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.12.2
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.84.104.254
!
```

Comment: Hello Ron,

Now also, even if I am trying to ping 192.168.12.2 (Router R2 f0/0) from the computer, it says the router is not reachable.
Please suggest...

Comment: Is the `10.84.104.254` address really the cloud gateway address? You need to use the address of the cloud that connects to R1.

Comment: I have configured the loopback adapter with the IP 10.84.104.254 (Cloud), R1 f0/1 is having an IP 10.84.104.1. Is this what you are asking about? 

Ping Result:
ping 10.84.104.1 : Possible
ping 192.168.12.1: Not possible (R1 f0/0)

Comment: I mean that there is an interface that connects to R1. The address of that interface should be the target of the default route. You could edit your question to show what your configurations are now. Leave the existing configurations there, too.

Comment: I have editted the question, & thank you so much Ron for all the help and support.

Comment: @ash, how does the cloud know where the R2 networks are? It is going to  know about the 10.84.104.x network for R1, but it needs to know to go to R1 to get to the R2 networks. Is it running OSPF, too, or do you have static routes configured on it?

Comment: I have not configured any static routes on R2, its just ospf which is configured.

Comment: No, not R2, the cloud. R2 knows how to get to the cloud network through R1 via OSPF. How does the cloud know how to get to R2 networks?

Comment: To be very honest. I have no idea, and I have no configuration which can define such. Please suggest.

Comment: The thing is, each element in your network must know where to send something, otherwise it gets dropped. If you are trying to send something from the cloud, the cloud knows how to get to R1 because they share a network. The cloud somehow needs to be told to go to R1 for any networks on the other side of R1. Routers get routes in three ways: directly connected, statically configured, or through a routing protocol.

Comment: Oh!!! Now I am getting your point. How to configure this or whats the best way to do that?

Comment: I really don't know what your cloud is, or how it is configured. For a Windows PC, you can configure static routes with the `route` command. The destination for all networks on the other side of R1 would be to the `10.84.104.1` R1 interface. You could run `route print` to see what routes your PC knows about.